# Static Scoping vs Dynamic Scoping

Tags: scope, ocaml

Consider the following Ocaml code:

```
let app f y = let x = 4 in (f y)+1 ;;
let proc x = let change z = z-x in app change (x+3) ;; 
(proc 2)
```

From what I understand, static scoping uses the structure of the code to determine the value of the variables, so in this case, `x` is replaced with `2` both in `change` and in `(x+3)`. However, what I don't understand is why dynamic scoping only replaces the `x` in `change` with `4` but not the `x` in `(x+3)` with `4`.

This is a bit confusing, I'm wondering if there's any trick to how to think through these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A free variable is a variable that's used in a function but isn't defined in the function. In your example code, the only free variable is the variable `x` of the function `change`:

```
let change z = z - x
```

The function `change` uses `x` but doesn't define it.

The essence of scoping is to determine what variable definition a free variable is referring to, what its *referent* is. In your example code, it comes down to determining the referent of the free variable `x` in the `change` function.

For static scoping, there is a single static referent for every free variable. The referent is determined by looking outward in the text of the program through statically containing blocks of code until a binding (a definition) is found. In OCaml, variable bindings are introduced by function definitions and by `let`. So you're looking for the nearest enclosing block of `change` that binds `x`. The nearest binding of `x` is the function parameter `x` in `let proc x =`. For the example call, it has the value 2.

For dynamic scoping, the referent is determined by looking up through the nested *function calls* that are active at the time the value is required. In other words, you want to find the innermost function in the call chain that defines a variable named `x`. If you pretend that OCaml has dynamic scoping (which it most definitely *does not*), the call chain looks like this:

```
proc => app => change
```

The function just outside `change` in the call chain is `app`, and it defines a variable named `x`. So for the example code, the free variable `x` of `change` refers to the variable `x` defined by `app`. In the example, it has the value `4`.

The `x` in `x + 3` is not a free variable. It's defined by `proc` and is used in `proc`. For the example call it has the value 2 no matter what scoping is used.

For what it's worth I don't think it's particularly useful to think of replacing variables with values. It's better to think of them as being bound to values.

I'd also like to say (though I probably shouldn't) that dynamic scoping is insane. The extra flexibility is definitely not worth the extra complexity in figuring out what's going on. It shouldn't be necessary to trace through chains of function calls to determine the binding of a variable. (In my opinion.)